# MongoDB HA with DRBD ( Active-Standby)

Tags: database, mongodb, replication, high-availability, drbd

I am working on MongoDB HA. Don't want to go with the HA approach  mentioned in mongo official docs due to resource limitation.

I have done the MySQL (Active-Active) HA with DRBD, corosync & pacemaker. I have done mongoDB HA (Active- Standby) with DRBD, corosync & pacemaker. I have tested it a small scale data. It's working fine.

I read that mongoDB with DRBD is not good approach & it can lead to data corruption.

Should i go with this approach ??
if not any other approach apart from official one ??

Comment: Any help on above ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing Active/Passive (Active/Standby) clustering, there is no difference between a MongoDB on DRBD vs. MongoDB on any other block device.

If you had multiple active MongoDB's accessing a dual-primary (Active/Active) DRBD device, that's where the potential for corruption would come in.